# Resample (or loop) using log mean

Tags: python-3.x, loops, time-series, resampling

Is there a way to resample using log mean? I have read the resample documentation and cannot find any options for log mean resampling.

I have a large dataframe with datetime index, with observations for every minute. I need to calculate the log mean for every 5 minutes for a range of variables (columns).

I have provided some code below showing some example data and the calculation i want to carry out. It might be, that if there isnt a log mean resampling function 'out of the box', that i will need to code a loop to do this...?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'db' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]}, index=pd.date_range('2019-05-02T00:00:00', '2019-05-02T00:14:00', freq='1T'))

df1 = df1.resample('5T').mean() # <------ is there a way to do log mean for this?

# The calculation i am need to do is:

df2 = np.log10(10**((df1[observation minute 1]/10)) + 10**((df1[observation minute 2]/10)) + 10**((df1[observation minute 3]/10)) + 10**((df1[observation minute 4]/10)) + 10**((df1[observation minute 5]/10)))

# Where 'observation minute 1,2,3,4,5' are the 5 minutes i want to resample for.

# The resulting df i need is:

df_result = pd.DataFrame({'log_mean' : [np.log10(10**((1/10)) + 10**((2/10)) + 10**((3/10)) + 10**((4/10)) + 10**((5/10))), np.log10(10**((6/10)) + 10**((7/10)) + 10**((8/10)) + 10**((9/10)) + 10**((10/10))), np.log10(10**((11/10)) + 10**((12/10)) + 10**((13/10)) + 10**((14/10)) + 10**((15/10)))]}, index=pd.date_range('2019-05-02T00:00:00', '2019-05-02T00:14:00', freq='5T'))
```

Any guidance would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can resample using any function of your choosing using `apply`:

```
df1 = df1.resample('5T').apply(lambda spl: 10*np.log10(np.mean(np.power(10, spl/10))))
```

or you can define it separately

```
def log_avg(spl_arraylike):
  return 10*np.log10(np.mean(np.power(10, spl_arraylike/10))))

df1 = df1.resample('5T').apply(log_avg)
```

this returns a dataframe with the following values 
2019-05-02 00:00:00 3.227668 
2019-05-02 00:05:00 8.227668 
2019-05-02 00:10:00 13.227668